# Почему не работает display: flex в safari

Tags: html, css, css3, scss

Столкнулся с проблемой flex-ов на маке, сафари не понимает свойство display: flex, во всех браузерах на винде все хорошо. Также шрифты становятся более жирные, но возможно это такая особенность данного шрифта)) Для добавления префиксов использую "gulp-autoprefixer",

scss

```
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
justify-content: space-between;
```

css

```
display: -webkit-box;
display: -webkit-flex;
display: -ms-flexbox;
display: flex;
-webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
-webkit-box-pack: justify;
-webkit-justify-content: space-between;
    -ms-flex-pack: justify;
        justify-content: space-between;
```

Comment: На всякий случай [https://caniuse.com/#search=flex](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex)

Comment: Сафари - это то, что должно отмереть как можно скорее. Если б вы указали версию вашего Сафари, можно было бы гадать тщательнее, а так - попробуйте использовать полифилл как раз для флексов в старых браузерах: https://github.com/jonathantneal/flexibility